# Writing Content of Textbox To .txt File

Tags: c#, textbox, .net

I want to write all the content of a textbox to a .txt file to the current directory. I wrote the following code however it throws a "wrong path name error". Where have I gone wrong?

```
string fileDateTime = "StepsGA-" + DateTime.Now + ".txt";
string fname = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileDateTime);
File.WriteAllText(fname, txtSteps.Text);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probablly want to do `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

This has the added advantage that if you sort by name, it will be in date order.

Answer (score 1):

may be DateTime.now includes ':' char? You can't use this char in file name...

Answer (score 0):

a file name cant contain /\^<>*!| you need to have formate date 
you may use  following code to formate your date 
String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", DateTime.Now); 
this will return date as 8 08 008 2008

so change your code as following 
string fileDateTime = "StepsGA-" + String.Format("{0:y yy yyy yyyy}", DateTime.Now) + ".txt";
string fname = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Environment.CurrentDirectory, fileDateTime);
File.WriteAllText(fname, txtSteps.Text);

hope this will work for you now